# Passing data between views and models in Flex MVC framework

Tags: apache-flex, model-view-controller, actionscript, mxml

I have never used Flex/Actionscript before so excuse me if I'm asking anything obvious but I have been working on this for 3 days (includes searching google and stackoverflow) before writing this post.

I have been asked to modify a game written in Flex 4 made with a mini-IoC-based MVC framework. Two mods I have been asked to make is a game over screen, which displays the final score and a difficulty selection on the introduction screen. I have made the game over screen, and successfully managed to get the controller to bring it up when the game timer runs out.

So for now, the game structure goes:

```
Intro View -> Game View -> Game Over View

    ^                            |
    |__________ (retry?) ________|
```

The first problem is getting the score to be passed from the mainGame ActionScript file to the game over screen.

Things I have tried:

- Importing mainGame in the gameOverViewBase and calling the mainGame.score variable in the gameOverView mxml file.

-EDIT!!! = the above method works if I change the score variable in mainGame to a constant, but if it remains a variable, the controller won't load the gameOverView and the game sits at an empty mainGame view.

- Making a function that adds to a new score variable in the gameOverViewBase whenever the player scores during the game.
- Passing the score as a parameter to the GameOverView when the MainGame ends

`controller.loadGameOver(score);`

This seemed like the most logical way to go about it. So I followed the function through the other components of the game setting the loadGameOver to take an integer as a parameter until I got to the main game actionscript file:

```
public function loadGameOver(score:int) : void
    {
        loadView(GameOverView);
    }
```

The loadView function (shown below) is where I get stuck because I can't see where to pass the 'score' parameter. It looks like this:

```
private function loadView(viewClass:Class, modelClass:Class = null) : void
    {

        var view:View = new viewClass();
        if(!view) throw new Error("Could not load view");

        viewContainer.removeAllElements();
        viewContainer.addElement(view);         

        view.controller = this;

    }
```

The second problem is the difficulty selection on the introduction screen. I have done this with 3 buttons (easy, normal, hard) in the mxml file and for every button in the ActionScript:

```
protected function onEasyButtonClick() : void
    {
        set = "easy"
        controller.loadMainGame(set);
    }
```

Once again, I end up at the above loadView function.

To sum up: I need to know how to pass the data between the views and models. If that's not the ideal method, I am open to any other methods that you think are better.

Thank You!

Ben

P.S. I can send my source code to anyone who would like to help :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify which MVC framework you're using which would be helpful. However, score should definitely be a property of a model and the model data should be accessible to the view either directly, perhaps via binding (thanks weltraumpirat), or via some intermediary class.

I would suggest you have a look at some of the existing view classes and try to figure out how they are fed the model data. You can use this approach to get the data you need for your view.

**[EDIT]:**

The `mainGame` property is not being set on your `GameOverView` instance so you're unable to access its `score` property either through binding or through trace. The `loadView` method of your controller class accepts a `Model` class reference which it uses to construct a new `Model` instance to be used by the new `View`. Unfortunately this is no use to you as your `GameOverView` needs the instance of `MainGame` which was created for the `MainGameView` (and which contains the current score).

I don't know if the following fits into the philosophy of the framework you're using. However, I would change the `loadView` method to accept an instance of a `Model` rather than a class reference, and create and cache a reference to an instance of `MainGame` when your controller is instantiated. That way you can pass the same `Model` reference to both the `MainGameView` and `GameOverView` when these are created.

```
    public class WhackAMoleBase extends Application implements IGameController
    {
        public var viewContainer:Group;
        private var mainGame:MainGame

        public function WhackAMoleBase() : void
        {
            super();

            // Create and cache an instance of the main game Model
            mainGame = new MainGame();

            addEventListener(FlexEvent.CREATION_COMPLETE, onCreationComplete);
        }

        public function loadIntroduction() : void
        {
            loadView(IntroductionView);
        }

        public function loadMainGame() : void
        {
            loadView(MainGameView, mainGame);
        }

        public function loadGameOver() : void
        {
            // Use the same instance of MainGame which the MainGameView 
            // has been using as the Model for the GameOverView
            loadView(GameOverView, mainGame);
        }

        // Accept a Model instance rather than a class Reference
        private function loadView(viewClass:Class, model:Model = null) : void
        {
            //Create a new instance of the supplied view
            var view:View = new viewClass();
            if(!view) throw new Error("Could not load view");

            //Clear any previous views in the container and add
            viewContainer.removeAllElements();
            viewContainer.addElement(view);

            //Property based dependency injection 
            view.controller = this;

            //There may or may not be a model required for the
            //requested view; check and instantiate appropriately
            if(model)
            {               
                //Give model reference to the controller
                //and link the view up to the model
                model.controller = this;
                view.model = model;
            }
        }

        private function onCreationComplete(event:FlexEvent) : void
        {
            //When the application is first created, we want to show the introductory view 
            loadView(IntroductionView);
        }

    }
```

Comment: In Flex, you probably want to use bindings for this.

Comment: its built round an example mini-IoC-based MVC framework, if that's any help? By 'property of a model', do you mean a public variable? 
@weltraumpirat I have used the [Bindable] tag on the variable too but it won't show the whole score label `Score: {mainGame.score}`

Comment: If you're trying to bind on the property then it will need to be either a public variable of the model, or accessible from the model via a public getter method. Alternatively some frameworks / implementations might choose to push the data out as part of an event object which is sent to interested views when the data changes. What do you mean when you say the binding won't show the whole score label?

Comment: Well if I try to directly access the score variable in the mxml file, the rest of the view loads, leaving out the entire label where the score from mainGame is being called. When I try to define a variable in the actionscript of gameover base like this: `protected var mainGame:MainGame;
  
  [Bindable]
  public var score:int = mainGame.score;`

The gameOverView won't even load and the game hangs in the mainGameView.

Comment: Can you trace the value of mainGame.score in your mxml file? With your second approach, do you see any errors when you run it?

Comment: Also, how do other views which make use of the score property access it from the model?

Comment: just learning how to trace/debug now, will get back to you on that. As for your second question, the only view which accesses the score variable from the mainGame.as model is the mainGameViewBase.as and mainGameView.mxml. They do this by importing the model and declaring it a Bindable, protected variable in the AS file. And the mxml file simply calls it with `mainGame.score`.

Comment: You definitely want to get comfortable with trace. Also have a look into whether you can set breakpoints in the IDE you're using. I'll have a look at your source code if you're still struggling. Stick it in a zip somewhere and give us the URL.

Comment: well i've got this common error where the process hangs at 57% when trying to load the debugger.... lame

Comment: warning: unable to bind to property 'mainGame' on class '...........:GameOverView'

This is the error I get when I run it through the debugger.

Comment: this is what i get when I trace `mainGame.score` : TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: See edit. Good work figuring out debugging; as you'll have realised, you're working blind without the console.

Comment: ah okay! thanks for the help! I actually figured out my own way of doing this by using the SharedObject library to write the score to a file and then access it in the GameOverView. Nevertheless, thanks!

Comment: That strikes me as being a rather convoluted way of passing data between views within the same MVC application. The result is that you unnecessarily end up with two versions of the same data, one residing in memory and the other on the user's computer. I think this method will become unmaintainable pretty quickly if you're required to add additional views which access model data at a later date. Just my tuppence worth, and if it works for you then that's cool. The best form of thanks would be to accept the answer and upvote it ;)